# Return data from a select in variable

Tags: node.js

I have a function that selects a table, but this select data is not inserted in the desired variable.

What I basically needed was to first execute select, but it seems to skip that execution

```
var msg = []; 
con.query ('SELECT * FROM dados' , (err, result) => {
    msg = result; ///this variable msg does not receive the result value 
});
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer( app );
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const mysql = require('mysql');

// conexao com o banco de dados 
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "dados_users"
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'public'));

app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine','html');

app.use('/', ( req , res ) => {
    req.render('index.html');
});

var msg = [];
con.query ('SELECT * FROM dados' , (err, result) => {
    msg = result; ///this variable msg does not receive the result value
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.emit('msg_existentes',msg);//retorna dados earmazenados na variavel msg 
    socket.on('recebe_do_front', data => {
        con.connect(function(err) {
            var sql = "INSERT INTO dados (nome, msg) VALUES ('"+data.nome+"', '"+data.msg+"')";
            con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("1 record inserted");
            });
        });
        msg.push( data );    
        socket.broadcast.emit('envia_para_usuario', data);   
    });
});

server.listen(3001);
```

Comment: have you checked content of err variable?

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection attacks.  Use parameterized queries to avoid this problem.

Comment: @AaA the return is null

Comment: I don't think it is skipping it, the code after your select will run before the code inside callback function.if you need your insert and io run after select is complete, you need to put it inside callback function of the con.query

Comment: I did something similar, but it includes more things and then it worked, thank you for the force.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Insert after Select is completed, you need to include insert inside callback function of `con.query` or like below

```
con.query ('SELECT * FROM dados' , (err, result) => {
    con.connect(function(err) {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO dados (nome, msg) VALUES ('"+data.nome+"', '"+data.msg+"')";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
                console.log("1 record inserted");
        });
    });
});
```

On the other hand if you are trying to run whole select and insert during connection `io.on('connection' ...` you need to include above select inside its callback function.

Hopefully someone with more knowledge of Node.js can clarify but if I'm not mistaken main code always runs to end before any callback functions are called.

Comment: I understand, well the way I did it worked very well.
What I did was call select only once, then store json, then when there are new records it adds locally.
 Many thanks for the force

Comment: By the way, you can tell me if the message data of a chat is correct to store in rows in the database or in json in a single column.